# Spring Data JPA query returning Object rather than specific class instance

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Can a Spring Data JPA `Query` unexpectedly return an `Object` instance rather than an instance of the expected entity class?

Given the following snippet...

```
public interface BlaRepository extends JpaRepository<BlaEntity, UUID> {

  ...

  @Query("FROM bla b JOIN b.dependency d " +
            "WHERE d.something = ?1 " +
            "AND b.somethingElse = ?2")
    Optional<BlaEntity> find(UUID something, String somethingElse);
```

Are there circumstances under which this query might return an `Object` instance?

Note that the issue occurs using a rather old version of Spring Boot Data JPA (1.5.x).

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a misunderstanding. Old Spring Data JPA versions don't support wrapping entities in an `Optional`, hence the `ClassCastException`. Closing.